# Access to container of Simple Injector MVC views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, sitecore, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

In a Sitecore project I've integrated Simple Injector using [this article](https://www.akshaysura.com/2016/07/19/tihidi-install-and-configure-simple-injector-di-for-a-sitecore-8-x-solution/)

It uses sitecore pipelines and then uses a method in App_start

```
namespace BBC.App_Start
{
    public class SimpleInjector : IPackage
    {
        public void RegisterServices(Container container)
        {
            GetContainer.RegisterServices(container);

            container.Register(() => new SitecoreContext(), Lifestyle.Scoped);
            container.Register(() => new Container(), Lifestyle.Singleton);
        }
    }
}
```

Simply I can inject container into controller constructor but can't have container in View files.

I tried to declare a static property in App-start and save container to it. but still I'm getting no registration type in Views

What is the best way to have container object in views?

Comment: You should not have any dependencies in your views. Views should be plain DTOs and the Controllers (or some other component) should create them. Neither should you inkect the Container itself into classes; that's an anti-pattern as well.

Comment: Third, you should *not* do `Register(() => new Container(), ...)`. That will register an empty Container.

Answer (score 1):

As [Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) suggests in his comment, the literal answer to your question is "you shouldn't do that - because it's not really the way MVC and DI are supposed to work". The more detailed answer goes something like this:

The job of your view is to present data that it has been passed via the Model. Views should not really contain logic. Very simple stuff like "if flag is false, hide this block of mark-up" is ok, but the more complex code to work out what the value of the flag is shouldn't be in the view.

MVC tries to make our website code better by encouraging you to separate presentation (*the View*) from data (*the Model*) and logic (*the Controller*). This should make our code easier to work with - So if you have processing that needs doing, then it should really be happening when your controller method runs.

If your view requires some special data, best practice suggests it should work it out in the controller method and pass it to the view in the model. The code might look more like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string SpecialData { get; set; }
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult DoSomething()
    {
        // do whatever processing is needed
        var somethingCalculate = resultFromYourOtherObject();
        // do other stuff

        var model = new MyModel() { SpecialData = somethingCalculated };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And then the View just needs to accept the `MyModel` class as its model, and render the `SpecialData` property - no logic required.

I think also it's considered a bad idea to have calls to fetch objects from your DI container spread about your codebase. For MVC apps, generally your DI container gets wired in to the process of creating a controller for a request when the app starts up. Rather than passing about a DI Container into your controllers, the DI framework extends the Controller-creation process, and the container isn't exposed outside of this. When the MVC runtime needs to create a controller, the controller-creation logic uses the DI framework to fetch objects for all the controller's dependencies.

Without more detail about what you actually want to achieve, it's difficult to say what the "right" approach to creating your object(s) here is, but the two most common patterns are probably:

1) **Constructor injection:** Your controller has a parameter which accepts the object required. The DI container creates this object for you at the point where it creates the controller, so your controller gets all its dependencies when it is created. Good for: scenarios where you know how to create the object at the beginning of the request.

```
public interface IMySpecialObject
{
    string DoSomething();
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    private IMySpecialObject _specialObject;

    public MyController(IMySpecialObject specialObject)
    {
        _specialObject = specialObject;
    }

    public ActionResult RenderAView()
    {
        // do some stuff
        var data = _specialObject.DoSomething();

        return View(data);
    }
}
```

As long as `IMySpecialObject` and a concrete implementation for it are registered with your DI container when your app starts up, all is well.

2) **Factory classes:** Sometimes, however, the object in question might be optional, or it might require data that's not available at controller-creation time to create it. In that case, your DI framework could pass in a Factory object to your controller, and this is used to do the construction of the special object later.

```
public interface ISpecialFactory
{
    ISpecialObject CreateSpecialObject(object data);
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    private IMySpecialFactory _specialFactory;

    public MyController(IMySpecialFactory specialFactory)
    {
        _specialFactory = specialFactory;
    }

    public ActionResult RenderAView()
    {
        // do some stuff
        if( requireSpecialObject )
        {
            var data = getSomeData();
            var specialObject = _specialFactory.CreateSpecialObject(data);
            var data = _specialObject.DoSomething();
            return View(data);
        }

        return View("someOtherView");
    }
}
```

But a good book on using DI may suggest other approaches that fit your specific problem better.